# Java - Read and write stream header

Tags: java, header, stream

I'm currently developing a simple chat-client and server for a project in school. Right now I have trouble with sending/reading information along with my objectoutputstream and objectinputstream, as an example of why I want this is so that I can verify a chat message was sent and received in it's entirety.

So I have looked around for any way to add headers to the packets I send over the network and stumbled onto the methods readStreamHeader() and writeStreamHeader(). My first question is, will these two methods do what I need them to do? Second, are there any kind of documentation on what these two actually do, I have been unable to find out enough about them. Third, is there any easier/better/more correct way of achieving my goal?

All I need is a little nudge in the right/any direction, kind of stuck right now. Hope I've provided a good enough question, first time trying here!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need streamheader for this purpose? You can simply write a socket program sending objects with TCP connection. I don't think you have to go that deep(packet level) for chat-client and server.
Here is a simple [demonstration](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html).

Comment: Other than sending messages between server and clients I will also need the server to be able to send a list of users connected and a list of topics you can join and chat about. How can I send requests to the server so that it knows what exactly to send back, or how to handle a message bound for a specific topic. I might be going about it in the wrong way? If so, what is the better way?

Comment: did you check the link i tagged with "demostration"? There is complete code. But you need to understand that you can send stream of objects from client to server which holds all the information you need.

Comment: Yeah, saw the link, I've based much of what I have on that code and other similar examples. But say if I want to send a msg-object to the server, and then I want to send a request for an updated userlist. How can I tell the server what is what?

Comment: You can exchange objects from server client. You can keep any information you want. Now you can figure it out yourself what logic you will use so that you can send the object containing updated userlist. My intention is to make you clear that you don't have to work with packets for such requirements.

Comment: Ok, guess I'll take your word for it =) Thanks for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: No problem. By the way, if you think my answer helped you out you can accept the answer.